# Umbraco 7 Limiting possible Tags values

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, propertyeditor

On our website, it is possible to tag content by a country list. This country list could be implemented as a tag control but I'm concerned about mis-spellings creeping in over time. However, the country list is very long (150+) so not ideal for a dropdown multiple control either.

What I'm looking to do is have a control that has the same type + autocomplete functionality as the existing tags control but limit the possible values to those retrieved from a database table.

I also want to be able to list all tags that a piece of content has been tagged against as well as searching for content based on tags e.g. GetNodesWithTags

Has anyone developed anything like this before? I've had a look at packages etc but can't see anything similar. Does anyone have any advice before I start off?

Comment: If you haven't already, try asking over at our.umbraco.org as well :-)

Comment: @JannikAnker Thanks - I have, find a two pronged attack tends to work better. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, using Tags datatype for this may cause a lot of problems :)

In my opinion, the perfect solution will be to use **nuPickers** (https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nupickers/) package and available there **TypeaheadList Picker**.

Depending of your additional requirements, you may use Lucene index / C# accessed source (totally custom - db, static, enum etc.) / XML file source as a prevalues for your control.

[image]

Then, you'll be able to create logic which will enable you to perform search based on this field as it will be a typical property with value on the nodes. Once again - suggested way is to use Lucene Examine index as it's tailored to be fast with searching. You can read more about searching with Examine here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/searching/examine/.

Hopefully it will solve your problem.